# how to fix "Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string" error in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have some problem with my wordpress theme.
My wordpress Error is:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in C:\wamp64\www\sanat\wp-content\themes\shokoohsanat\includes\ninzio-functions.php on line 472

line 472 in nizino-function.php:

```
echo '<a href="'.$first_term_link.'">'. $first_term->name .'</a>';
```

line 473 in nizino-function.php:

```
echo $text_before.get_the_title().$text_after;
```

PHP7. I have Checked Wordpress version 4.7.13 and 5.2 and 5.1

Comment: With your message error, you are using WP_Error  class and tried convert it to string. So you get this error. Let post full code in file ninzio-functions.php. Or you can view info of WP_Error in https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error

Comment: I uploaded a part of the code here: https://mertaa.ir/php-Error.txt . i cannot fix it with docs. I'm not pro. help me plz...

Comment: Did you rremove code line 472 and 473, it run success?

Answer (score -1):

Replace line 472 with these:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $first_term ) ) {
    echo 'No terms found';
} else {
    echo '<a href="'.$first_term_link.'">'. $first_term->name .'</a>';
}
```